Handling Redis Connection Events with Spring Boot Data Redis
With Spring Boot Data Redis, is there a way to detect and handle Redis connection activation and deactivation events?
I am using Spring Integration to listen to a Kafka topic, perform some processing, and write to another Kafka topic. I want to listen for Redis connection events so that I can pause my processing flow if the Redis connection goes down and resume it when the connection is restored.
